# Attached Property: 'System.TypeInitializationException' when setting default value

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties, argumentexception

I want to set a default value of my Attached Property, but when I do I get:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Oef_AttDepProp.exe

Without the default value, things work fine.
This is some sample code I used:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEigenaarProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
"Eigenaar", typeof(clsPersoon), typeof(UIElement), 
new UIPropertyMetadata(new clsPersoon("test", "test"), PropertyChanged));

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Browsable(true)]
public clsPersoon Eigenaar
{
 get
 {
  return _persoon;
 }
 set
 {
  _persoon = value;
 }
}

public static void SetEigenaar(UIElement element, clsPersoon value)
{
 element.SetValue(IsEigenaarProperty, value);
}

public static clsPersoon GetEigenaar(UIElement element)
{
 return (clsPersoon)element.GetValue(IsEigenaarProperty);
}

private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
 if (obj is Window1)
  ((Window1)obj).Title = GetEigenaar(((Window1)obj)).ToString();
}
```

It's the "new clsPersoon("test", "test")" which seems to be the cause the problem, but that is only a very simple class with a 2-string-constructor.

**Edit**: When trying to set the property through a click event, instead of the window_load, I get an innerException of: "Default value for the 'Eigenaar' property cannot be bound to a specific thread."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically exceptions of type `TypeInitializationException` are thrown when an exception occurs in the static constructor. Look there.

Also, from the inner exception:

> Default value for the `Eigenaar` property cannot be bound to a specific thread.

This usually means that your property is not thread-safe (e.g., doesn't inherit from [`System.Windows.Freezable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx)). Check this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2cb12481-ef86-40b7-8333-443598d89933/) for gory details and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.defaultvalue.aspx) for details about default values for dependency properties.

Comment: Indeed, with the new inner exception I found the same thing (at first I didn't get that inner exception, because I set the value in window_load).
When I inherit from Freezable, I'm not able any more to inherit from DependencyObject in my clsPersoon class though... Do I have to chose now, which one to use, and does losing the DependencyObject have any downsides?

Comment: @Avalon: `Freezable` inherits from `DependencyObject`.

Comment: Ow, I see, didn't think that far through, mea culpa.
Thanks, to the both of you!