# Default value for the 'Options' property cannot be bound to a specific thread

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I find that when I change a class from

```
public class MarkdownEditorOptions : ObservableObject
```

to

```
public class MarkdownEditorOptions : INotifyPropertyChanged, DependencyObject
```

as I wanted to use dependency properties, I get the error

> Default value for the 'Options' property cannot be bound to a specific thread. ...\Views\ShellView.xaml

Options is declared as a dependency property on `ShellViewModel`

```
public MarkdownEditorOptions Options
{
    get { return (MarkdownEditorOptions)GetValue(OptionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OptionsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OptionsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Options", typeof(MarkdownEditorOptions), typeof(ShellViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(new MarkdownEditorOptions()));
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See these questions

- [Why Would a Dependency-Property Implementation Crash My Application When I Provide a Default Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168648/why-would-a-dependency-property-implementation-crash-my-application-when-i-provid)
- [Attached Property: 'System.TypeInitializationException' when setting default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102013/attached-property-system-typeinitializationexception-when-setting-default-valu)

Your Dependency property is not thread safe, meaning that it doesn't inherit from System.Windows.Freezable.
Change DependencyObject to Freezable and it'll work since Freezable derives from DependencyObject.

Comment: Should I then always use `Freezable` over `DependencyObject` then? Or is there some downsides associated with it?

Comment: Hey I found that its a Read Only object, what if I need to modify dependency properties in it?

Comment: For future readers, I was trying to use the default value to set up an initial instance to bind to, and due to the issue @JiewMeng mentioned where the framework forces it to be readonly, was not able to do so. By instead simply assigning the initial value for the property in the constructor of the viewmodel I was able to achieve what I wanted.